# Is there a recover_post hook to go with trash_post hook?

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm using the `trash_post` hook to set a flag in a custom table to indicate that this item is "deleted", but when the user chooses to restore that post, what hook can I use for that? I couldn't find anything on this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference, but maybe there's another way to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code for WP 3.3.2, it seems that `trash_post` is actually `wp_trash_post`.  From the `wp_trash_post()` function in `/wp-includes/post.php`:

```
do_action('wp_trash_post', $post_id);

add_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_trash_meta_status', $post['post_status']);
add_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_trash_meta_time', time());

$post['post_status'] = 'trash';
wp_insert_post($post);

wp_trash_post_comments($post_id);

do_action('trashed_post', $post_id);
```

So ... I'd double check the hook you're using to set your initial flag.

However, there *is* a hook you can use to detect when a user restores a post.  It's aptly named **`untrash_post`**.

Here it is in action from the same core file:

```
function wp_untrash_post($post_id = 0) {
    if ( !$post = wp_get_single_post($post_id, ARRAY_A) )
        return $post;

    if ( $post['post_status'] != 'trash' )
        return false;

    do_action('untrash_post', $post_id);

    $post_status = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_trash_meta_status', true);

    $post['post_status'] = $post_status;

    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_trash_meta_status');
    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_trash_meta_time');

    wp_insert_post($post);

    wp_untrash_post_comments($post_id);

    do_action('untrashed_post', $post_id);

    return $post;
}
```

Comment: `trash_post` does work, but do you recommend I use `wp_trash_post` instead? I found it in sitepress.class.php: `add_action('trash_post', array($this,'trash_post_actions'));`

Comment: I can't speak for anything in `sitepress.class.php` since it's part of a premium plugin that I don't have. But I did do a fresh download of WP 3.3.2, and there is no action called `trash_post` in core.  It's possible that WPML (the plugin that includes `sitepress.class.php`) defines the `trash_post` hook as a wrapper for `wp_trash_post`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `trash_post` was changed to `wp_trash_post` for WP 3.3 (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18974), so add your action to *both* hooks to make sure it works with 3.3 and later.

Comment: Yes, you are right about. The repository I searched had `trash_post` in that plugin, however the install that I tested `trash_post` on did not have this plugin (it was a new install) and `trash_post` did work. This doesn't make any sense though.

Comment: See my last comment (was editing when you posted). WP renamed the hook in 3.3 ... Seems when you change a post status to "trash" it calls a dynamic hook `post-status_post-type` which evaluates to `trash_post` ... they renamed the hook to avoid collisions. So your code will *still* work ... only you're tying to a completely different hook than you thought :)

Comment: How can it still work now though, when there's no reference of it in 3.3.2? (Saw your updated comment that answers this). So the safest bet is to use `wp_trash_post` and `wp_untrash_post` for consistency.

Comment: There *is* a reference to it. When you change a post to "trash" status, the status transition hook (`post-status_post-type`) will call `trash_post`. But that's not the action you should be hooking on to. It will work, but you should really be using `wp_trash_post` instead because that's what it's for. The plugin you're referencing just failed to update when WP changed things.

Comment: Last question: I'm using the `save_post` hook, but it appears that `wp_save_post` also works, but I'm seeing that `save_post` is by far more widely used. Do you have a recommendation on that?

Comment: I can't find a `wp_save_post` in core at all ... do you mean `wp_insert_post`?  If so, it's called back-to-back with `save_post` and both pass in the same arguments. 0 difference between the two.

Comment: I gotcha. Thanks for your time and help. I wish it was a bit more consistent, but everything is now working thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

When a post is untrashed, WordPress calls [`wp_untrash_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/post.php#L2093). That calls two actions: `untrash_post` prior to untrashing and `untrashed_post` after. Both pass the post ID as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere on the edit.php is a `wp_untrash_post` but the documentation page is empty (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_untrash_post), maybe if you take a look to the source you may be able to find a way 
http://wpseek.com/wp_untrash_post/
http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-admin/edit.php.source.html